# Ember-data update a record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't find anything anywhere, but it is possible to modify a record inside the store with ember-data ?

I know there is `store.createRecord( 'user', { name: bob});`
But how can I do to be able to modify a specific record ?

Like this : `store.updateRecord( 'user', recordToModify, newData)` ?

Is there anything already available by ember-data or I should just write it by myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DS.Model provides a [save](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_save) method:

```
recordToModify.set('someAttribute', 'someValue');

recordToModify.save().then(function() {
  // Success callback
}, function() {
  // Error callback
});
```

Comment: But what is the `record` value in this case ?

Comment: An instance of DS.Model. From your example, `recordToModify`.

Comment: Like `var recordToModify = store.find('user', id);` ? or I completely misunderstood ?

Comment: Yep, that's right. And the same goes for the resulting object from `store.createRecord`.